# Why pointers which point at the same place, after dereferencing give different value?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Sample code:

```
int main()
{
int* i = new int(4);
int* j = i + 1;
j = new int(5);
cout << *i << endl;
cout << *j << endl;
}
```

> will print:
>   4
>   5

```
int main()
{
int* i = new int(4);
int* j = i + 1;
j = new int(5);
cout << *i << endl;
cout << *(i + 1) << endl;
}
```

> will print:
>   4
>   0

Do not get what is the difference

Comment: `j = new int(5);` changes where `j` points. You seem to mistakenly think it means to create an int at where `j` is currently pointing

Comment: `j = i + 1; j = new int(5);` is equivalent to `j = new int(5);`.

Comment: The initialization in `int* j = i + 1;` (a) makes `j` point just after the `int` object you just allocated (which is not useful) and (b) is immediately clobbered when you assign a new value to `j`.

Comment: make sense, thank you.

Comment: The second example exhibits undefined behaviour, since `*(i + 1)` does not point at a valid object.   Calculating `i + 1` is okay, dereferencing it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check out your code line by line:

> ```
> int main() {
>     int* i = new int(4);
>     int* j = i + 1;
>     j = new int(5);
>     cout << *i << endl;
>     cout << *j << endl;
> }
> ```

```
// Let's just say that an int is 32bits or 4bytes

int* i = new int(4); 
// Declaring a pointer to type int and initializing it with a value of 4

int* j = i + 1; 
// Declaring a pointer to type int at 4 memory address location's past i. 

// For example: if i's memory address is 0x0004 
//    then j would be at memory location 0x0008. 

// However j will contain any arbitrary value or garbage.

// before calling your next line `j = new int(5);`
// do this:
std::cout << i << " " << j << "\n";
std::cout << *i << " " << *j << "\n;
// Here you will see the address increase by a value of 4 in hex 
// which is a 4 byte width provided the int is 32bits or 4bytes

// You will also see that when dereferencing the pointers that the 
// memory location that i is point at does have the value 4, 
// but the memory location that j is pointing at 
// has garbage or any arbitrary value.

// With your next line of code:
j = new int(5); 
// now you are taking j and pointing it to another location and assigning 
// to that memory location the value of 5. 
// You changed where j was pointing in memory.

std::cout << *i << std::endl; // self explanatory: dereferencing i and print value
std::cout << *j << std::endl; // same as above but for j
```

---

> ```
> int main() {
>     int* i = new int(4);
>     int* j = i + 1;
>     j = new int(5);
>     cout << *i << endl;
>     cout << *(i + 1) << endl;
> }
> ```

Every line above but the last line is the same. Let's check out the last line.

```
std::cout << *(i + 1) << std::endl;
// Here you are dereferencing the pointer that is 4 bytes past i.
```

Basically you are trying to print whatever is stored in memory location 4 bytes on a 32bit machine past i's location in the second part of your code.

If the wording is unclear refer to this picture diagram:

[image]

Comment: Why the negativity without explanation?

Comment: @M.M edited my post. I tried to make it a little bit more readable and clearer to understand. I know what I was trying to say; just that sometimes the words don't come out right.

Comment: @M.M when using the `new` operator it places the integer that the pointer is pointing to on the heap. `int* i = new int(4);` i itself is on the stack yes; but the memory it is pointing to is heap memory.

Comment: @M.M. Ah; from the second comment; yes; j does hold (i+1)'s memory address but the value at that address is being assigned a value of 5.

Comment: @M.M. Is that a little clearer? Just removed the distinction between the heap & stack altogether.

Comment: Getting there... "j will contain garbage" section  could be improved. `j` contains a valid pointer;  *the memory location being pointed to by `j`* can be said to contain garbage.

Comment: @M.M This should do it; I even added a graphic for visualization.

Answer (score 4):

You are lucky or unlucky to get a value in your second code when using `cout << *(i + 1) << endl;` The `i+1` means to move to next location in memory with a length of `int`. Since you didn't assign anything on the next location. There is no value at that location. It returns 0 but it could be anything!

You use lots of `new` here to open memory in heap which is not necessary. Many Java users may have habit to use new, but we need to be thoughtful on when to use `new` in C++. You also need to use `delete` to release memory if you use `new`.